# How to get element attribute value in webdriverio using typescript with await syntax?

Tags: typescript, async-await, webdriver-io

Subj.

More info:

The following code examples does not compile:

```
let id = (await browser.element(selector)).getAttribute('id');
```

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript ...: Property 'getAttribute'
>   does not exist on type 'RawResult'. (2339)

```
let id = (await browser.element(selector).getAttribute('id'));
```

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript ...: Type of 'await' operand
>   must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then'
>   member. (1320)

Comment: Typescript await logic will generate Javascript code that captures the Promise if there is one to capture.  Otherwise you have to put the code into a Task and await the task.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/typescript-asyncawait-construct-john-peters

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why but the `webdriverio` definitions declares [an object that looks like a promise but is called Client](https://github.com/celador/webdriverio-intro/blob/master/typings/browser/ambient/webdriverio/webdriverio.d.ts#L22-L29).

In TypeScript you can `await` functions that return a `Promise`. You can wrap the `webdriverio` API using your own functions and promises:

```
import * as webdriverio from "webdriverio";

function getTitleAsync(url: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: "chrome" } };
        const client = webdriverio.remote(options);
        client
            .init()
            .url(url)
            .getTitle()
            .then(function (title) {
                resolve(title);
            })
            .end();
    });
}
```

Then you can await your function:

```
(async () => {
    const title = await getTitleAsync("https://duckduckgo.com/");
    console.log(title);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is pretty simple if your wdio is running in synchronous mode - so no any async/await needed:

```
it('get attribute', () => {
    browser.url('')
    let classes = browser.element('html').getAttribute('class')
    console.warn('ATRRIBUTE CLASS IS:', classes)
})
```

Your `classes` variable will be simple string object.

Just make sure you are set property sync: true in config:

```
// Per default WebdriverIO commands getting executed in a synchronous way using
// the wdio-sync package. If you still want to run your tests in an async way
// using promises you can set the sync command to false.
sync: true,
```